# c++ tcp socket speed changes

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Here's something I can't understand. I developed a C++ video streaming Windows app. When streaming multiple video streams between 2 PCs on a local network, I get some latency and frame drops. However, if I add a TeamViewer connection between the 2 machines, there is no more latency and frame drops.

The opposite would be logical, right? What I'm I doing wrong?

For me, it looks like there is some buffering on the connection. Adding a Teamviewer connection seems to force a "push" of the data on the network.

I tried with a VNC connection instead of TeamViewer, but the latency and frame drops remains.

My streamer can use TCP or UDP. I only get the lag with TCP, not with UDP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is not likely to get a good answer. It does sound as if you have a mystery on your hands, but there isn't enough information for anyone to help you. Perhaps if you could provide some specific measurements, code (see [mcve]), Wireshark traces, etc., the question could be rephrased in a way that identifies a specific problem. Or, if you need help in those areas, ask one or more specific questions about network diagnostic techniques (of course after searching for existing answers first). Good luck!

Comment: I trust you have already disabled Nagle's algorithm on your TCP connection (via setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, ...) ?

Comment: yes, I tried with and without TCP_NODELAY.